# How to specify a default value, or couple of values on an Elementor SELECT2 control?

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-select2, elementor

Working on Elementor with WordPress, does anyone know how I can specify a default value, or an array of default values on a SELECT2 control?

Here is the code of the control:

```
$this->add_control( '27_listing_types', [
    'label' => __( 'Listing Types', 'my-listing' ),
    'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
    'fields' => [ [
          'name' => 'type',
          'label' => __( 'Select Listing Type', 'my-listing' ),
          'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT2,
          'options' => $listing_types,
          'default' => '',
          'label_block' => true,
    ] ],
    'title_field' => sprintf(
        '{{{ (%s)[type] || "n/a" }}}',
        trim( wp_json_encode( $listing_types ), '"' )
    ),
] );
```

Where `$listing_types` is an array: `{ "member-b2b": "Member-B2B", "member-b2c": "Member-B2C" }`

Thanks to anyone who can help!

EDIT:
After trying to add a default value according to Jasie's answer, here is how it acts:

I still need to press on "add an element".

[Screenshot: empty listing types list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN9m9.png)

Then it adds an element with a preselected value "Membre-B2B", which is the value I specified in control's code, but this selected item isn't functional and it doesn't feed the widget:

[Screenshot: after adding an element with default value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rFbP.png)

Should be like that to work properly:

[Screenshot: after adding an element and manually selecting the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpwHZ.png)

EDIT:

[After setting parameter 'multiple' => true,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg8Cx.png)

EDIT:

I finally got it working, here is the right code :

```
$this->add_control( '27_listing_types', [
    'label' => __( 'Listing Types', 'my-listing' ),
    'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
    'fields' => [ [
        'name' => 'type',
        'label' => __( 'Select Listing Type', 'my-listing' ),
        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT2,

        'options' => [
            'membre-b2b' => 'Membre-B2B',
            'membre-b2c' => 'Membre-B2C',
        ],
        
        'label_block' => true,
    ] ],
    'default' => [
        [
            'type' => 'membre-b2b',
        ],
        [
            'type' => 'membre-b2c',
        ]
    ],
] );
```

This does create a repeater control with an array of two default values.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: does it work, if you use SELECT2 control WITHOUT REPEATER control, stand alone? have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

As per official docs: https://developers.elementor.com/elementor-controls/select2-control/#Arguments

`default` is an argument of the `Select2 Control`:

> string|array   The selected option key, or an array of selected values
> if multiple is set to true.

Example from here https://developers.elementor.com/elementor-controls/select2-control/#Usage :

```
$this->add_control(
    'show_elements',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Show Elements', 'plugin-domain' ),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT2,
            'multiple' => true,
            'options' => [
                'title'  => __( 'Title', 'plugin-domain' ),
                'description' => __( 'Description', 'plugin-domain' ),
                'button' => __( 'Button', 'plugin-domain' ),
            ],
            'default' => [ 'title', 'description' ],
        ]
);

$this->end_controls_section();
```

UPDATE:
As per official docs, the `REPEATER`control works like this with defaults:
https://developers.elementor.com/elementor-controls/repeater-control/#Usage

You create the SELECT2 control first and you add it to the Repeater by doing this: `'fields' => $repeater->get_controls(),`. See also the `default` param:

```
$this->add_control(
    'list',
    [
        'label' => __( 'Repeater List', 'plugin-domain' ),
        'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::REPEATER,
        'fields' => $repeater->get_controls(),
        'default' => [
                [
                    'list_title' => __( 'Title #1', 'plugin-domain' ),
                    'list_content' => __( 'Item content. Click the edit button to change this text.', 'plugin-domain' ),
                ],
                [
                    'list_title' => __( 'Title #2', 'plugin-domain' ),
                    'list_content' => __( 'Item content. Click the edit button to change this text.', 'plugin-domain' ),
                ],
        ],
        'title_field' => '{{{ list_title }}}',
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but that doesn't work as expected unfortunately.I still have to press on button "add en element", then it adds an element with "semi" preselected value (hard to tell without a screenshot)

Comment: please edit your question and do add a screenshot :-)

Comment: "or an array of selected values if multiple is set to true". did you set the param `'multiple' => true,`?

Comment: Yes, no fundamental change, please see screenshot

Comment: saw your last update, but I cannot get anything working unfortunately :( Actually I just realized this Elementor control is a repeater control with select2 fields.